# Trying to sort out the mess of Under New Management after using the console to fix it (SPOILERS)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I spent a great deal of time finishing jobs for Vex and Delvin, having heard about "Restoring The Thieves Guild To It's Former Glory", often repeating cities far more than necessary to improve my skills. It got to a point where I had completed all four cities and the special jobs and I just kept going until I realized I've counted over five quests but it was no longer progressing.

So I figured this was a bug where it required console commands to fix, and I did. I reset the chain of the Thieves Guild quests, which triggered my chance to be able to speak to Brynjolf. This appeared to have fixed my position in the Thieves Guild, but during the ceremony, I noticed a new member Karliah... I figured she was just another new recruit who was to be added during my progression in Restoring the Thieves Guild so I didn't think much of it. I had already spoken with the new members as I did my way with Vex and Delvin, and Karliah had no special dialogue so I thought she wasn't essential.

Later on (much later on), I came across something about "Twilight Sepulcher" and found the location. Looking further into this, I learned that this was to be part of a quest from the Thieves Guild which involved Karliah and Mercer Frey. Mercer never provided any dialogues and his impatient attitude left me to dislike him so I never bothered with him. But now I'm in this mess where I can't find Karliah and Mercer just disappeared after the console command fix... Furthermore I learned that I was supposed to explore with Mercer and find Karliah (or something like that).

**Was I supposed to speak with Mercer instead of Brynjolf? Was I supposed to come across Karliah during these quests? Did I just skip an entire quest line? Did I break my game?**

I'm not much for posting Q&A or the like but this feels like an ugly game-breaking mess to the point where I don't even know what to ask and found no similar posts.

Comment: yes you broke the entire thieves guild chain most likely

Comment: @amaranth Answer in answer post maybe?

Comment: If you still know which console commands you ran, it would help a lot to post those. If you don't know, meaning you ran console commands without writing down what they were, and if you also didn't make a save first, then you have made a huge mistake.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't keeping up with my own post. I left that round of my game and started a new one to go through the known bugs first so that I progress properly.

I believe this was the console command I used to reset the Guild chain "setstage TGLeadership 10".

Also I lost the ability to trade with Tonilia after I spoke with the Khajiit she was asking about. I can't remember exactly, but I think I picked up both quests from Delvin and Tonilia at the same time and I could no longer get any dialogues from her.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure from your description which quests you’ve done, but the only way forward after using the console to change your position in a large questline is to use the console some more.

You can find a list of Thieves Guild quests at [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_(faction)). Start out by noting which quests you’ve finished and which ones you want to do. It sounds like none of the remaining quests are going to start by themselves, but you can hopefully get them to start using console commands. You may need to check the list of commands at both [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) and [The Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_(Skyrim)), because the list of commands on each site is incomplete.

It looks like you were supposed to meet [Karliah](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Karliah) during the [Speaking with Silence](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Speaking_With_Silence) quest. That quest may be difficult to fix at this point, but you might be able to skip it by finishing that quest in the console and forcing [The Pursuit](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Pursuit) to start.

At minimum, you can explore [Snow Veil Sanctum](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Snow_Veil_Sanctum) (the location for Speaking with Silence) simply by unlocking the door with the console. I did that without joining the Thieves Guild and it worked fine, except for a part at the end where Karliah was supposed to be there, but she wasn’t.

For more specific advice, I think we’d need to know which quests you’ve finished, what console command you ran, and what quest or dialog you’re trying to activate. You can hopefully get a lot of the rest of the questline to work, but it may take a lot of editing from the console.

One thing you could try is to move yourself to [Mercer’s](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Mercer_Frey) location and see where he is:

```
player.moveto 22651
```

Perhaps he’s waiting for you in a quest location somewhere, and has some dialog that could advance your progress. If you use that command but don’t see Mercer anywhere, he might be deactivated. You could re-enable him, but I don’t know if that would make things better or worse for your quest progress:

```
prid 22651
enable
```

Also, I suggest keeping a lot of saved games, so you can back up if the console commands you try make things worse.

Comment: I’ve never joined the Thieves Guild, but I did a bit of console editing to unlock some of the Thieves Guild quest content.

Comment: Yeah I do believe I've broken my game. Using that command "player.moveto 22651" only brings me to the Cistern's desk but no Mercer. I don't remember exactly which quests I had and/or completed because anything I did with the thieves guild was a long looooooooong time ago and I finally came back to the Guild after I completed the main quest. Last thing was completing small jobs for Delvin and Vex then one from Tonilia about the Khajiit and that's where I was stuck. I never got "Speaking with Silence" and "The Pursuit" (I don't think). Only Vex, Delvin and Tonilia were all I could interact with.

Comment: @user167850 From that description and from your comment above, if you feel like trying to fix the thieves guild quests in this play through, it _might_ help if you do `resetquest TGLeadership`. If you ran `setstage TGLeadership 10` that early in the questline, you skipped a lot of quests. Or you could just forget it and try `setstage TGLeadership 200`—that might just make you Guild Master and finish the thieves guild questline without you doing anything.

Comment: That "resetquest TGLeadership" only creates Under New Management (actually duplicates it). The last thing (besides the pages and pages of shill/fishing/bedlam etc. quests) was Loud and Clear. I'd rather do the quests instead of skipping them entirely. What I noticed as well is that I haven't completed No Stone Unturned yet, so far only found 22/24... I wounder if that has anything to do with it?

Comment: I just noticed that the next quest from Loud and Clear is Dampened Spirits which involves Maven Black Briar, but at this point she's the jarl of Riften and I can't get any dialogues from her. I did read somewhere about the main quest having a chance to mess up the thieves guild quest lines, I think that's where I've fallen in the cracks of.

Comment: @user167850 Did you finish Loud and Clear? Did you do any of the “reputation quests” listed under “Special Job Quests” [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_(faction)#Special_Job_Quests)? I don’t think that No Stone Unturned should impede your progress for the other quests. What happens if you finish Loud and Clear in the console (if it isn’t finished yet) and try to force [Dampened Spirits](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dampened_Spirits) to start? Or maybe just start Dampened Spirits the normal way, if Loud and Clear isn’t marked as finished yet.